# php 5.4.3 how to add new extension

Tags: php, windows, php-extension

I am currently upgrading my php version to 5.4.3.

How can I add a new PHP extension in 5.4.

In php 5.3 and older versions we are adding ".dll" files in the ext folder and adding that dll path into the php.ini file. But in php 5.4 the "ext" folder seems entirely different from older versions.

I need to add sourceguardian dll (ixed.5.3.win) file to my php.ini. How can I add that?

Comment: What extension are you adding? In what way is the `ext` folder different in 5.4 to 5.3? I'd have thought it would be a case of dropping in the DLL and adding a config line to your php.ini file(s).

Comment: The ext folder structure has not changed between PHP 5.3 and 5.4. Please be more specific what your problem is.

Comment: Please check there is some changes between php 5.3.6 and 5.4.3 ext folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find a PHP 5.4 compatible sourceguardian dll.